# Why do the elementary row operation work in different ways for different elements?

Tags: for-loop

I am working on Gaussian algorithm in JavaScript. I struggle with elementary row operations. You can see the output from my code on the attached photo, where the first 2d array is A and the second 2d array is the result of the function [My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BugKk.png)

I tried to print an array made of elements equal to variable "d" to see if my "d" makes any sense. It works properly for all theelements except A[1][3] and A[2][3]. [My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OybKx.png)

Why does it work this way?